# Ng-bootstrap unable to display tootip

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using ng-bootstrap for displaying tooltips in my Angular project. I am not able to display tooltip. No console errors. Code follows:

`HTML`

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" ngbTooltip="Tooltip">
  Customized tooltip
</button>
```

`app.module.ts`

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
imports: [
  NgbModule.forRoot()
]})
export class AppModule { }
```

`Component`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbTooltipConfig} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  providers: [NgbTooltipConfig]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(config: NgbTooltipConfig) {
    config.placement = 'right';
    config.triggers = 'click';      
}
```

}

How to resolve this?

Comment: Your component isn't declared in your AppModule. So you shouldn't even be able to display it.

Comment: I added. I didn't display that code here. Updated now.

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/7WIhaC8WW8nBne3yaSia?p=preview. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, as I just did.

Comment: I realized didn't add bootstrap css in index.html. After adding I am able to display tooltip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue is, you forgot to add css :

Put this in your `index.html` :

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

> Dependencies This repository contains a set of native Angular
> directives based on Bootstrap's markup and CSS. As a result no
> dependency on jQuery or Bootstrap's JavaScript is required. The only
> required dependencies are:
>
> Angular (requires Angular version 4 or higher, tested with 4.0.3)
>
> Bootstrap CSS (tested with 4.0.0-beta)

For more details , please read :

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started